# I was trying to implement sprinting in my unity game but my speed inly changes for a split second then goes back to walking speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So when playtesting my speed is 3 but when I press left shift it **sometimes** goes to 6 but instantly goes back to 3 could someone please help I've been trying to fix this for a long time??
CODE BELOW:
NOTE SPRINTING CODE IS BOLD

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //variables
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 3f;
    public float runSpeed = 6f;
    public float crouchSpeed = 1.5f;
    public float gravity = -19.62f;
    public float jumpHeight = 1f;

    public Transform groundcheck;
    public float grounddistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    public Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    public bool isCrouching = false;
    public bool isRunning = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundcheck.position, grounddistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0) {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded) {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
        }

        **if(Input.GetKeyDown("left shift")) {
            speed = runSpeed;
            jumpHeight = 1.5f;
        } else {
            speed = 3f;
            
        }**

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity *Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: SPRINTING CODE IS IN ASTERICS

Comment: It's quite an easy solution you should use ```Input.GetKey()``` it returns true as long as your key is held down by the player, instead of using ```Input.GetKeyDown()``` which only returns true for the very first time when you press the key.

Comment: see you just directly assigned the value 6 to the variable speed. Do you need answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Input.GetKey` instead of `Input.GetKeyDown`.

Your current variant will only return true once per pressing the button.